# How do I get dBA noise levels within Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

We are looking to record the sound levels in our space over time, so that we can message people if it gets too noisy for the neighbours. We therefore need to look at the microphone to get the sound level it is currently experiencing, then store that in dBA in our database. We are using Python3, MySQL and Ubuntu 18.04.

We already have a Python program that gathers metrics from lots of sources and throws them at the database. All I need now is a function that calls something that can tell me the current noise level.

To do this, I have been looking at the [soudmeter](https://pypi.org/project/soundmeter/) library written by Shichao An. It seems pretty awesome! Shichao An gives examples of using the command line which can generate a CSV, however I would like to pass the values straight from Python to the database without the command line or a CSV. Shichao An also mentioned using the [monitor class](https://github.com/shichao-an/soundmeter/blob/master/soundmeter/monitor.py), however I am not sure how to implement that down to just a function I can call and return one number.

I've got this so far;

```
import soundmeter
import math

def root_mean_square():
    current_rms = 0
    # DO SOME STUFF
    return current_rms


def decibel_a():
    current_dba = log(20, 10) * (root_mean_square() / 20)
    return current_dba
```

Can you point me in the right direction? Where `#DO SOME STUFF` is currently, how do I get the soundmeter library to return the current noise level?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Python [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) module. Looks like you have the sound level part figured out, sqlite3 should get you the rest of the way there.

Comment: I am fine with the SQL side of things; we already have many metrics being loaded into the database. It's just the sound level part that I *don't* have figured out lol! What should I replace `#DO SOME STUFF` with?

Comment: Sorry, I've been doing backend work lately, and everything looks like an SQL nail.

We have to make some assumptions, e.g. that you have a list or an array of dba values to be passed in to root_mean_square, which should do just what the name implies:

* Square each entry
* Take the mean of the squares
* Take the square root of the mean

[This site](https://dosits.org/science/advanced-topics/introduction-to-signal-levels/) has a decent explanation. And [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40963659/root-mean-square-of-a-function-in-python) has an ex solution for `numpy`.

Comment: The `decibel_a` function above does convert RMS to dBA. It's getting the RMS that I'm stuck on. As far as I can see, the soudmeter library looks at your built in microphone and returns RMS. What I can't work out how to do is get the soudmeter library to do that within my existing python program.

Comment: "...you have a list or an array of dba values to be passed in to root_mean_square" I do not have these, that's what I'm looking to get from the soudmeter library, but don't know how.

Comment: Have you solved your problem @JamesGeddes? I also want to do exactly the same: measure ambient volume and output in dbA. I messed a bit with soundmeter, but haven't got from their output into dbA.

Comment: @BFurtado Unfortunately not yet. We will be working on it at https://github.com/GeekZoneHQ/web/issues/370 so we would be tremendously grateful of any help on it :D